# JSON image and Core Data in Swift 3

Tags: json, swift, core-data, swift3

How to save JSON image in Core Data, Swift 3?

I have [a url](https://www.zdoof.com/api/zTimeline/ztimeline_bind?Created_by=3234&Created_on=01/jan/2017&Updated_on=14/june/2017&PageIndex=1&PageSize=10) - it is a `GET` request. I want to save `profimg` and `UID`.

How do I save and fetch them in Swift 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beginning with iOS 11 and Xcode 9, Core Data supports a `URI` data type that would be suitable for storing the image URL like the `profimg` field from your JSON. You could also use Core Data's string type, either for convenience or if you're supporting iOS 10. The `UID` field is an integer, so choose whichever of Core Data's integer types is large enough to hold the maximum value. If you're in doubt as to the maximum `UID`, you can safely go with Core Data's "Integer 64" type.

Save and fetch just like any other Core Data attributes.

Comment: Hi tom ,Please see the second answer ,that i have done the problem like this . But the problem is when i am fetching the data and showing in the table view ,If there is no  internet connection ,The app chrashes

Comment: That's a completely different question from this one. You should post a new question that includes information about how you're using network connections and what exactly happens when the app crashes-- error messages, etc.

Answer (score -1):

func clearData() {

```
    let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate

    if let context = delegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext{


        do {




            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Mydata")

            let objects = try(context.fetch(fetchRequest)) as? [NSManagedObject]




            for object in objects! {
                context.delete(object)

            }

            try(context.save())


        } catch let err {
            print(err)
        }
    }


}


func setupData() {

      clearData()

    let urlWithParams = "https://www.zdoof.com/api/zTimeline/ztimeline_bind?Created_by=4490&Created_on=01/jan/2017&Updated_on=14/june/2017&PageIndex=1&PageSize=50"

    Alamofire.request(urlWithParams, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { response in

        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(_):
            if let data = response.result.value as? NSArray{
                self.myHelp = [myHelperClass]()





                for allData in data  {

                    let help = myHelperClass()
                   let jsonID = (allData as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "UID") as! NSInteger
                    help.myId = String.init(describing: jsonID)

                    help.myName = ((allData as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "Name") as! NSString) as String

                    self.myNameArray.append(help.myName)

                    //                            person.setValue(myName, forKey: "name")


                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in


                        let myUrlString = "https://www.zdoof.com//"

                        let myprofileImage = (allData as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "profimg") as! NSString
                        help.myStringImageArray = myUrlString  + (myprofileImage as String)




                       let midImage = ((allData as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "mid_img") as! NSString) as String

                        help.myStringPostImageArray = myUrlString + (midImage as String)




                    })





                    help.Yumms = ((allData as AnyObject).value(forKey: "Postlike") as! NSString) as String


                    let kUserDefault = UserDefaults.standard



                    //                            person.setValue(Yumms, forKeyPath: "postlike")

                    let myId = (allData as AnyObject).value(forKey: "UID") as!NSInteger
                    help.myidString = String.init(describing: myId)
                    //                            person.setValue(myidString, forKey: "uID")


                    help.Rebcol = ((allData as AnyObject).value(forKey: "Rebcol") as! NSString) as String
                    //                            person.setValue(Rebcol, forKey: "rebcol")


                    help.UTYPIMG = ((allData as AnyObject).value(forKey: "UTYPIMG") as! NSString) as String
                    //                            person.setValue(UTYPIMG, forKey: "uTYPIMG")

                    help.Created_on = ((allData as AnyObject).value(forKey: "Created_on") as! NSString) as String
                    //                            person.setValue(Created_on, forKey: "created_on")

                    help.UTYP = ((allData as AnyObject).value(forKey: "UTYP") as! NSString) as String
                    //                            person.setValue(UTYP, forKey: "uTYP")

                    help.comments = ((allData as AnyObject).value(forKey: "Postcomment") as! NSString) as String

                    //                            person.setValue(comments, forKeyPath: "postcomment")

                    help.Details = ((allData as AnyObject).value(forKey: "Details") as! NSString) as String


                    //                            person.setValue(Details, forKeyPath: "details")
                    help.myPost = ((allData as AnyObject).value(forKey: "Share") as! NSString) as String


                    //                            person.setValue(myPost, forKeyPath: "share")

                    help.myDate = ((allData as AnyObject).value(forKey: "zDate") as! NSString) as String


                    //                            person.setValue(myDate, forKeyPath: "zDate")


                    let myPTYPEInteger = (allData as AnyObject).value(forKey: "PTYPE") as!NSInteger

                   help.myPTYPE = String.init(describing: myPTYPEInteger)
                   let myIdInteger  = (allData as AnyObject).value(forKey: "ID") as!NSInteger
                    help.myId = String.init(describing: myIdInteger)


                    self.myFunction(nameFunc: help.myName, yummFunc: help.Yumms, myIdFunc: help.myidString, RebcolFunc: help.Rebcol, UTYPIMGFunc: help.UTYPIMG, Created_onFunc: help.Created_on, UTYPFunc: help.UTYP, commentsFunc: help.comments, DetailsFunc: help.Details, myPostFunc: help.myPost, myDate: help.myDate ,imageArray: help.myStringImageArray , postImageArray: help.myStringPostImageArray , myUId: help.myId , myPpTypeFunc: help.myPTYPE , myIId: help.myId )



                    kUserDefault.set(self.ID, forKey: "ID")
                    kUserDefault.set(self.PTYPE, forKey: "PTYPE")
                    kUserDefault.set(self.UID, forKey: "UID")
                    kUserDefault.synchronize()


                }




            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in

                self.myTable.reloadData()
            })
            break

        case .failure(_):
            print(response.result.error!)
            break

        }


    }




}




func myFunction(nameFunc: String , yummFunc : String , myIdFunc : String , RebcolFunc: String , UTYPIMGFunc : String , Created_onFunc : String, UTYPFunc: String , commentsFunc : String , DetailsFunc : String ,myPostFunc : String , myDate : String ,imageArray : String , postImageArray : String , myUId : String , myPpTypeFunc : String , myIId : String )
{



    let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate

    if let context = delegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext{


        let person = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Mydata", into: context) as! Mydata


        person.setValue(nameFunc, forKey: "name")

        person.setValue(yummFunc, forKeyPath: "postlike")
        person.setValue(myIdFunc, forKey: "uID")
        person.setValue(RebcolFunc, forKey: "rebcol")
        person.setValue(UTYPFunc, forKey: "uTYPIMG")
        person.setValue(Created_onFunc, forKey: "created_on")
        person.setValue(UTYPFunc, forKey: "uTYP")
        person.setValue(commentsFunc, forKeyPath: "postcomment")
        person.setValue(DetailsFunc, forKeyPath: "details")
        person.setValue(myPostFunc, forKeyPath: "share")
        person.setValue(myDate, forKeyPath: "zDate")
        person.setValue(imageArray, forKeyPath: "profimg")
        person.setValue(postImageArray, forKeyPath: "mid_img")
        person.setValue(myUId, forKey: "iD")
        person.setValue(myPpTypeFunc, forKey: "pTYPE")


        do {

            try(context.save())
        } catch let err {
            print(err)
        }


       loadData()

    }



}
```

func loadData() {
    let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate

```
if let context = delegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext {

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Mydata")



    do {



      people = try(context.fetch(fetchRequest)) as? [Mydata]





    } catch let err {
        print(err)
    }

}
```

}

I have done like this but the problem is when there is internet connection ,it is working .without internet app chrashes